# javax.smartcardio.CardException: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: WINDOWS_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: java, mifare, pcsc

We are using Mifare 4k card and Gemalto Prox SU Contact less reader.
When we are trying to authenticate the sector, we are getting following exception and this is not occuring every time
but only on one client machine

```
May 20, 2014 4:02:43 PM com.tcs.smartcard.Mifare4KUtils authSector
SEVERE: authSector
javax.smartcardio.CardException: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: WINDOWS_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
    at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.doTransmit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.transmit(Unknown Source)
    at com.tcs.smartcard.Mifare4KUtils.authSector(Mifare4KUtils.java:114)
    at com.tcs.smartcard.Mifare4KUtils.authenticateKeyBlockToFormat(Mifare4KUtils.java:426)
    at com.tcs.smartcard.Mifare4KUtils.writeKeyBlockForFormat(Mifare4KUtils.java:677)
    at com.tcs.smartcard.IssueCardApplet$TaskInit.doInBackground(IssueCardApplet.java:691)
    at com.tcs.smartcard.IssueCardApplet$TaskInit.doInBackground(IssueCardApplet.java:584)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: WINDOWS_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
    at sun.security.smartcardio.PCSC.SCardTransmit(Native Method)
    ... 13 more
```

Please help on this.

Comment: Can you provide code here...